# Convert row items into columns based on condition

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to convert row items into columns based on a given condition?

I am trying to convert row items based on row condition. For instance I have row items 1-31(day extracted from a date) and my condition is to return only days 1-7. I tried the following query but it returns the entire row items(days 1-31):

```sql
SELECT tblemployee.idnum AS ID_No, Concat(lname,", ",fname,"") AS Name,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=1,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=1,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=2,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=2,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=3,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=3,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=4,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=4,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=5,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=5,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=6,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=6,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=7,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=7,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=8,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=8,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=9,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=9,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=10,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=10,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=11,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=11,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=12,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=12,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=13,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=13,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=14,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=14,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=15,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=15,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=16,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=16,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=17,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=17,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=18,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=18,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=19,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=19,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=20,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=20,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=21,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=21,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=22,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=22,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=23,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=23,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=24,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=24,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=25,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=25,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=26,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=26,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=27,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=27,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=28,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=28,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=29,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=29,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=30,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=30,ot,NULL)) OT,
 MAX(IF(day(m_date)=31,basic,NULL)) BSC, MAX(IF(day(m_date)=31,ot,NULL)) OT
 FROM tblmanhours INNER JOIN tblemployee
 ON tblmanhours.idnum=tblemployee.idnum
 WHERE m_date BETWEEN '2013-11-24' AND '2013-11-30'
 GROUP BY tblemployee.idnum
 ORDER BY Concat(tblemployee.lname,", ",tblemployee.fname,"");
```

What condition will I add to receive my expected result?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want the columns to dynamically adjust to a given amount of days?

Comment: Yes Sir, based on the 'BETWEEN' condition.

Comment: The `where` clause will filter rows. There is no way to filter columns. You will have to dynamically create the query